# Ошибка Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как исправить ошибку в коде?

```
foreach (TreeViewItem objTreeviewItem in tv.Items)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem objTre in objTreeviewItem.Items)
    {
        if (objTre.Header.Equals(textTitle.Text))
        {
            objTre.IsSelected = true;
            s = objTreeviewItem.Items.IndexOf(tm);
            current = s;
            vit = objTreeviewItem as TreeViewItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: s - стринг, не?

Comment: Нет ошибку показывает вот здесь foreach (TreeViewItem objTreeviewItem in tv.Items)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var objTreeviewItem in tv.Items)
```

Это сурово, но проблему должно решить :)

Comment: А вообще у меня есть нехорошее подозрение, что objTreeviewItem.Items имеет тип ItemCollection а не TreeViewItem. Лучше проверьте через пошаговую отладку.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде отсутствует тот фрагмент, где коллекция заполняется. Возможно, действительно в `ItemsCollection` содержатся объекты типа `String`, а не типа `TreeViewItem`?

Comment: Коллекция заполняется до этого так в другом методе tv.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()). А как мне его преобразовать правильно в TreeViewItem.

Comment: Так в циклах и должно быть ItemsCollection или нет? Как мне тогда по другому получить родительские и дочерние items treeView в цикле?

Comment: Я вам предложил сделать пошаговую отладку и использовать неопределенный тип var. Сделайте это, поставьте breakpoint в цикл foreach и там можно будет посмотреть, какой тип примет эта переменная. Вот его и используйте (var вообще в c# использовать нежелательно, но для отладки сойдет)